# Angular find value from HTML class

Tags: angular, typescript

The `Person` Object contains the field `schoolId`. However, the `School`  object(Not shown here) contains the `schoolName` of the school. What I want to display in the td is the `schoolName` instead of `SchoolId` found in the `Person` Object. How can I do this ?

```
<tr *ngFor="let person of this.persons">                                 
  <td >{{person?.schoolId}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: It depends on how your School objects are stored, your template should probably refer to a function in your component that would take care of selecting the right School

Comment: `(Not shown here)` doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not fully understand your question but maybe it can help you. It all depends on your school object and where it is located.

```
  <tr *ngFor="let person of this.persons">                                 
     <td >{{person?.school?.schoolName}}</td>
  </tr>
```